# Is it possible to add custom field in Users table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

If yes, how this can be done please ?

I'm connected using "system" user and I tried the following command but it didn't work.

```
alter table sys.all_users add Piwpiw varchar(1);
```

I receive the error message saying that this table doesn't exist.

Hoever, when I query it, it works.

```
select * from SYS.all_users;
```

returns around 30 users;

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could, it would be a spectacularly bad idea.  Modifying objects in the data dictionary immediately makes your database unsupported and will almost certainly create issues down the road when you want to do something like apply a patchset or upgrade the database.  There is a good chance that it will cause some recursive SQL statement to fail as well when you try to do something like modifying a user.  You shouldn't even be creating new objects in the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` schema.

If there is some additional information that you want to record about a user, create an additional table in a schema other than `SYS` or `SYSTEM` that stores this information.

Assuming that you count as a "default user" any user created by any Oracle-delivered script whether or not it is run at database install time or later, and assuming that you don't manually create a user with the same name as any user an Oracle script would create, the easiest option would probably be to get one of the various [default password lists](http://www.petefinnigan.com/default/default_password_list.htm) available online and compare against the users listed there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I need is just a way to distinguish between the default users created with the database and the users created manually. Is there any way to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

A typical application logged on to an Oracle Database will have some sort of an admin-module where application-users are created and granted proper privileges.
Additional user-attributes are stored in a separate table *my_app_users* owned by the application schema-user.

To list application users, you join all_users and my_app_users something like this:

```
select u.username, m.firstname, m.lastname, m.comments, m.attrib1, m.attrib2, etc.. 
from 
  all_users u, 
  my_app_users m
where
  u.username = m.username;
```